# Execute function for every helper and events

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to build an automatic error reporting system for my meteor app but there is one little thing I'm not able to do right now. I would like to know if it is possible to create some sort of wrapper that would execute each time a helper or an event is called, for any template.

I've searched in blaze.js to see how they handle it and possibly edit it but I guess altering this file is not the way to go.

I found nothing about that, and at this point, I'm not sure it is even possible.

EDIT: I found some sort of a solution but it's far from perfect.

I've created a globalHelper :

```
Template.registerHelper('checkError', (tmplName, helperName, ...args) => {
    try {
        return Template[tmplName].__helpers.get(helperName).apply(this, args);
    } catch(error) {
        let trace = error.stack.split('\n').map(function (line) { return line.trim(); })
        let obj = {
            text: "" + error,
            date: parseInt(Date.now() / 1000),
            function: trace[0].split('@')[0],
            template: tmpl,
            trace: trace.slice(0, trace.length - 1)
        }
        Meteor.call("logNewCrash", obj, function(err, res) {
            if (!err) {
                Bert.alert("Une erreur est survenue et à été communiquée à un administrateur. Elle sera traitée dans les plus brefs délais.", "danger");
            }
        })
    }
});
```

It works as expected but I need to call this helper instead of the original ones, for exemple :

```
<template name=templateName1>
    {{#if checkError 'templateName1' 'helperName1' arg1 arg2}}
        <!--do something-->
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

with the following helper :

```
helperName1(arg1, arg2) {
    if (arg1 == arg2)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

EDIT 2 :

So I dropped my previous work to create a meteor package.

I successfully overrode `Blaze._wrapCatchingExceptions` like so :

```
Blaze._wrapCatchingExceptions = function (f, where) {
    if (typeof f !== 'function')
        return f;
    return function () {
        try {
            return f.apply(this, arguments);
        } catch (error) {
            let trace = error.stack.split('\n').map(function (line) { return line.trim(); })
            let obj = {
                text: "" + error,
                date: parseInt(Date.now() / 1000),
                function: trace[0].split('@')[0],
                template: Template.instance().view.name.split('.')[0],
                trace: trace.slice(0, trace.length -1)
            }
            Meteor.call(configuration.method, obj, function(err, res) {
                if (!err) {
                    Bert.alert(res.msg, "danger");
                }
            });
            Blaze._reportException(error, 'Exception in ' + where + ':');
        }
    };
};
```

However, some errors aren't handled by Blaze but by Tracker. This is where it's getting frustrating, I can't get my Tracker override to work.

I tried to override `Tracker._runFlush` and `_throwOrLog`but either I got a `Maximum stack size exceeded` or my function is just not called at all.

I probably was doing it wrong.

What am I missing ?

Thanks

Comment: `I've searched in blaze.js to see how they handle it and possibly edit it but I guess altering this file is not the way to go.` Can you show please where you searched and the code that made you think you could not change it? I am asking because I have overridden Template lifecycle methods for one of my packages, so I know it's possible.

Comment: I didn't really know where to search at first, that's why I'm thinking this is probably not how I should do it but the file is located in `.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/blaze.js` and this code is the following : https://codeshare.io/2K16l7

Comment: This is the local build folder, it changes Everytime you change a file so no use to override things there. You can take a look in my package how I override the onCreated function: https://github.com/jankapunkt/meteor-template-states

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, I'm gonna take a look at your package, thank you :)

Comment: Well, after looking at you package, I don't really see how I could adapt it for my case. I don't undestand how I can kinda append my try catch to my helpers / events / onCreated / onRendered

Comment: Ok after trying for a bit, I managed to do it. I'm just wondering how you can set some options. For exemple, in my blaze overriding function I spawn an alert; Do you know how I can set an option to use a custom message without having to edit the package code ?